# Gnuplot: ContourPlot (formating to Grid Data)

Tags: gnuplot, contour

My Data looks like this:

```
2015-08-01 07:00    0.23    0.52    0.00    0.52    9   14.6    14.6 14.6   67  8.5 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.6    14.1    14.1    16.3    1016.2  0.00      0.0   156 0.22    156 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.003   0.000   23.9    39  9.1 23.4    0.05    23  1   100.0   1   1.8797836153192153  660.7143449269239

2015-08-01 07:01    0.25    0.53    0.00    0.53    0   14.6    14.6    14.6    67  8.5 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.6    14.1    14.1    16.3    1016.2  0.00    0.0 153 0.22    153 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.003   0.000   23.9    39  9.1 23.4    0.00    23  1   100.0   1   1.8894284951616422  657.3416264126714   105 73  121 163

2015-08-01 07:02    0.25    0.52    0.00    0.52    0   14.7    14.7    14.6    67  8.6 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.7    14.2    14.2    16.1    1016.2  0.00    0.0 139 0.20    139 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.003   0.000   23.9    39  9.1 23.4    0.00    24  1   100.0   1   1.8976360559992214  654.4985251906015

2015-08-01 07:03    0.26    0.53    0.00    0.53    0   14.7    14.7    14.7      67    8.6 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.7    14.2    14.2    16.1    1016.3  0.00    0.0 139 0.20    144 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.003   0.000   23.9    39  9.1 23.4    0.00    23  1   100.0   1   1.9047561611790007  652.0519661851259

2015-08-01 07:04    0.25    0.53    0.00    0.53    0   14.7    14.7    14.7    67  8.7 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.7    14.2    14.2    16.2    1016.3  0.00    0.0 141 0.20    141 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.003   0.000   23.9    39  9.1 23.4    0.00    24  1   100.0   1   1.903537153899393   652.4695341279602

2015-08-01 07:05    0.25    0.52    0.00    0.52    0   14.8    14.8    14.7    67  8.7 0.0 --- 0.00    0.0 --- 14.8    14.3    14.3    16.3    1016.3  0.00    0.0 148 0.21    148 0.0 0.00    0.0 0.002   0.000   23.9    39  9.1 23.4    0.00    23  1   100.0   1   1.897596925383499   654.5120216976508
 ........
 ........
```

i want to plot the 43rd row in relation to the 3rd and 25th row :-) So those are the rows want to pick out of the file:

```
0.23 156 660.7143449269239
0.25 153 660.7143449269239
0.25 139 654.4985251906015
0.26 139 652.0519661851259
```

I want to set the `660.7143449269239` in relation to the `0.23` and `156` and plot a 2d contour plot .

I read the documentation but I don't know if those rows are sufficient for a Contour Plot or if  I need to alter them and if so, can I do this in gnuplot or do I have to rewrite the file tiself?

does my data need to look like:

```
0.23 156 660.7143449269239(0.23,156)
0.25 153 660.7143449269239(0.25,253)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to go (comments through the code):

```
set dgrid3d        # enable 3D data read from a scattered data set in file
set contour base   # enable contour drawing 
set view map       # if you want to see the graph from above (2D plot)
unset surface      # do not plot the surface, only the contour

# finally, plot your data selecting columns 3, 25, and 43
splot 'datafile' using 3:25:43
```

Comment: okay thanks, so I end up with rounded z values for the Contour Plot is that correct? That s what dgrid3d does?

Comment: Yes. Since your data seems to be scattered (it seems to be measurements of an experiment or other event), it is necessary to use `dgrid3d` in order to compute the contours. `dgrid3d` interpolates (through averages or splines) the z values into an uniform grid in the xy-plane. Then the interpolated points is plotted instead of the original data. You can control the way `dgrid3d` interpolates/averages the data (type `help dgrid3d` in gnuplot). If your data is already uniformly distributed, it is not necessary to use `dgrid3d`.